# No telemetry trigger in TB

Tags: monitoring, iot, thingsboard

Is it possible to trigger an alarm when there is no telemetry from the device for a specified time or for a given number of polling periods?

This trigger has the same meaning as a [Dead man's switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch) for humans.

Or what is the best way for TB to detect a broken connection, assuming that not every IoT device can keep an open TCP/MQTT/etc session for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thingsboard's builtin rules engine may help you on this, [Official Docs](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/re-getting-started/)

BTW, there is a nice user guide to help you detect inactive/offline devices, see [here](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-inactivity-alarm/)

Comment: Hi Balun, 
I was looking through to find some help with inactivity alarms and followed the [guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/create-inactivity-alarm/) posted. 

I am running in to the issue where the alarm is not being created and was wondering if you could help me. 
I created an inactivityTimeout of type integer for 10000 (ten seconds)
I then edited the root rule chain to add the create inactivity alarm with alarm type:Inactivity TimeOut  and added the clear alarm  with alarm type: Inactivity TimeOut

No alarms are being raised